# AWS RDS parameter group showing "Pending-Reboot" after mysql upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

we upgraded our AWS RDS mysql instance from 5.5.42 to 53 and we applied the original parameter group to this instance.

However when I checked the rds instance's configuration details, the Parameter Group value remains "pending-reboot" even though I've manually rebooted the rds.

How do I fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: A manual reboot is the fix for this. Are you sure you rebooted after changing the parameter group?

Comment: Yes, I've rebooted many times manually no change! :-(

Comment: Weird. Did you click "apply immediately" when you changed the parameter group?

Comment: I copied the original parameter group and applied it to the rds instance. Apply immediately was checked then.  The site is working ok with this rds instance but I guess our parameters are not being applied.

Comment: I would open a ticket with AWS support. The parameter group change should be applied on reboot.

Comment: I'm not signed up for aws support as it costs extra money. What other options do i have to seek aws support?

Comment: You can raise a support request in the AWS forums. You may not get a prompt response though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi so I found a solution which is quite simple. I had to make a minor edit to the parameter group (any one of the many variables will do), and save the changes. After that I rebooted the rds instance and now the parameter group is in-sync.

Comment: In theory RDS should save you some time, in practice you need to learn all its gotchas.

Comment: This issue still exists. I rolled back to the previous parameter group, rebooted, applied the new parameter group again, rebooted. It says in-sync now.

Comment: 5 years later, this is still happening

Answer (score 1):

The above solution didn't work for me. My case was that I had the default parameter group attached to the instance originally. Then I had to change it to enable log replication. Then I wanted to change it back to the default one.

When I tried that, I ran into this issue of pending reboot no matter how many times I rebooted.
And then I tried editing the default parameter group but AWS doesn't allow that. So I created a new parameter group, choose the default as a starting template, gave it some name like `default-pg-13-copy` and used that.